# optimal sequence to be followed for studying topics like dp

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I am a novice to algorithms and data structures. I recently started participating on codeforces and spoj etc.for solving questions  i need to study dp,greedy algorithms,graph algorithms,data structures.what should be my strategy for studying or rather sequence and what data structures i need to know for competitive programming?

Comment: Why don't you just solve some tasks to see what's relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All in all there shouldnt be an "optimal" sequence. Its all about understanding the topic. Since not two people can learn with the same speed, there shouldnt be something like an "optimal" sequence. But its good to learn basic approaches of each topic.

There are alot Tutorials out there, which explains the most fundamental thing in any topic. E.g. Youtube covers most graph problems. Even DP and so can be found there. Especially on [Topcoder Tutorials](http://help.topcoder.com/data-science/competing-in-algorithm-challenges/algorithm-tutorials/) there is alot you can learn.

On the other hand you will learn nearly nothing, if u dont have to think for yourself. So solving such puzzles is a must. I would recommend [this site](http://acm.timus.ru/) (especially for dp). Just check the "problem set" link on the site and look for dynamic programming.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you this book: [Competitive Progamming](http://books.google.com.ar/books?id=tjKYoAEACAAJ), by Halim. Is very complete, and newbie-compatible.